# Post method call is not working as expected because of @sap/approuter

Tags: http-status-code-301, http-redirect, sap-cap

On making the post call with json as it's payload to the backend server through sap app router, It is returning with the redirect url along with the status code 301 and because of that browser redirects the call with GET method to the backend server.

So, How can the POST call made to the back end through sap app router from the browser?